# Create different title level with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, header, report

I'm desperately try to create a report which should look like this:

---

Page header

---

**Title 1**

- Title 2

  - Title 3

    - Title 4
    - Data
- Title 2

  - Title 3

    - Title 4
    - Data

---

Page footer

---

The title 1 to 4 have to repeat themself each page. My first though was using subreport but since the page header and footer is not possible in subreport, I'm stuck. I also tried table with table header but I wasn't able to do it either.
If you have any idea they are welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Here is more details of what I'm trying to do:
[image: Main report]

The fisrt Static row is my Title1, I've put the properties, RepeatOnNewPage= True, KeepWithGroup = after, FixedDate=True.
I made a group on 1 just to have a block. Then each of the two static row inside the detail group are filled with another tablix that have my different title inside.
The header of the inside tablix render correctly on each page, but the first row only render on first page and I cannot understand why.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add each title to be a 'Row Group' and nest under the other.  To do this in 'Design' mode under 'Row Groups' you should start out with just 'Details', right click and choose 'Add Parent Group.  I would use a header to keep data on a different row but you don't have to. For the highest grouping once a grouping is set, right click the 'Row Groups' corresponding group and hit 'Group properties'.  Select 'Page Breaks' on the left pane and click 'Between each instance of a group'.  Voila you now have page groups breaking on the top most data and the other data grouping below it.

Comment: I tried to do as you said but I wasn't able to make it work. i added some more info in my question.

Comment: You need a different group for each level.  You should have 4 groups and a detail level with each group corresponding to your 'Title' group.